# AES Encryption with IV not working in iOS

Tags: java, objective-c, ios4, aes, ios5

I have a requirement to AES Encrypt (with initial vector) an NSString value.But it gives different output on comparing with the java code provided below.In Java it is delivering the correct result.What could be the reason?

For that I have used the code below:

**iOS**

---

```
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key 
{
// 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

// fetch key data
[key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

//See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
//equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
//That's why we need to add the size of one block here
size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                      keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128 ,
                                      INTIAL_VECTOR /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                      [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                      buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                      &numBytesEncrypted);
if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
    //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
    return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
}

free(buffer); //free the buffer;
return nil;
}
- (NSString*)hexStringFromData:(NSData *)data
{
unichar* hexChars = (unichar*)malloc(sizeof(unichar) * (data.length*2));
unsigned char* bytes = (unsigned char*)data.bytes;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    unichar c = bytes[i] / 16;
    if (c < 10) c += '0';
    else c += 'a' - 10;
    hexChars[i*2] = c;
    c = bytes[i] % 16;
    if (c < 10) c += '0';
    else c += 'a' - 10;
    hexChars[i*2+1] = c;
}
NSString* retVal = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharactersNoCopy:hexChars
                                                       length:data.length*2
                                                 freeWhenDone:YES];
return [retVal autorelease];
}
```

---

The implementation snippet is :

```
NSData *InputData = [@"mahi" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
NSData *encryptedData = [InputData AES256EncryptWithKey:ENCRYPTION_KEY];   
NSString *encryptedHexString = [self hexStringFromData:encryptedData];
NSLog(@"Encrypted HexString : %@",encryptedHexString);
```

---

### Java

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


    import javax.crypto.Cipher;

    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;


    public class MCrypt {


            private String iv = "fedcba9876543210";

            private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
            private SecretKeySpec keyspec;

            private Cipher cipher;

            private String SecretKey = "0123456789abcdef";


            public MCrypt()
            {

                    ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());


                    keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");


                    try {
                            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");

                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();

                    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {

                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();

                    }
            }

            public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception

            {
                    if(text == null || text.length() == 0)

                            throw new Exception("Empty string");


                    byte[] encrypted = null;


                    try {
                            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);


                            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(padString(text).getBytes());

                    } catch (Exception e)

                    {                       
                            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());

                    }

                    return encrypted;

            }

            public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception

            {
                    if(code == null || code.length() == 0)

                            throw new Exception("Empty string");


                    byte[] decrypted = null;


                    try {
                            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);


                            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));

                    } catch (Exception e)

                    {
                            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());

                    }
                    return decrypted;

            }



            public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)

            {
                    if (data==null)

                    {
                            return null;

                    }

                    int len = data.length;

                    String str = "";

                    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {

                            if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16)

                                    str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);

                            else
                                    str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);

                    }
                    return str;
            }



            public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {

                    if (str==null) {

                            return null;
                    } else if (str.length() < 2) {

                            return null;
                    } else {

                            int len = str.length() / 2;

                            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];

                            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {

                                    buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);

                            }
                            return buffer;

                    }
            }



            private static String padString(String source)

            {
              char paddingChar = ' ';

              int size = 16;
              int x = source.length() % size;

              int padLength = size - x;


              for (int i = 0; i < padLength; i++)

              {
                      source += paddingChar;

              }

              return source;
            }

    }
```

Comment: Using `String.getBytes()` can definitely be a problem because it is using platform default charset, not utf-8.